# How can I make an IP address always resolve the same MAC address on a Mac?

Tags: macos, networking, ip

I am doing some config with a flashed router, someone has provided me with an example using Windows, but I am using a Mac. So, I need to execute the command below on a Mac:

```
set neighbors "Wireless Network Connection" "192.168.1.1" "F8-B1-11-BF-**-**"
```

I tried the linux command

```
ip neigh add 192.168.1.1 lladdr F8-B1-11-BF-**-** dev en0
```

but this complained that `ip` was not a command.

---

I have a TP-LINK access point that has a custom build of DD-WRT. This is still in testing so there are some issues. One of them being that on installation the LAN MAC is incorrect so I have to log in via wireless (which comes online and I can connect to).

The access point isn't responding properly, so I need to add a static route in the ARP table to link the address `192.168.1.1` to the MAC address of the access point – at least I think.

Comment: You probably want the `arp` command.

Comment: It would help greatly if you told us what it is you're trying to achieve. The questions is far from clear.

Comment: Hi Alex! Please register your account on [SF], then log in using the same account here. Your accounts will be associated with each other and you can post comments, edit your question, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your wireless interface is configured so 192.168.1.1 is in the local subnet, all you need to do is:

```
sudo arp -s 192.168.1.1 F8:B1:11:BF:**:** temp
```

Note that `sudo` will prompt for your admin password (*not* the root password if you have set one); it will not echo as you type.

Answer (score 0):

Install iproute2 (or whatever your distro calls it) for the ip command. Depending on your distro you may also need to run it as root or with sudo.